# My if statement not executing properly (skipping if)

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to code blackjack and I'm done, but I have this one issue. For the dealer taking more cards it's supposed to keep taking more cards until the "dealerTotal" is 17 or higher. But, I have the problem that the dealer will always only take one card and then stand. This code worked before and would keep taking another card until it was over 16. But, now it doesn't work, and I've used some version diff checking and nothing is different.

```
if (playerTotal <= 21)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's two cards are: " << dealercard1 << " & " << dealercard2 << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;

    while (loop == 1) // will keep looping until it breaks (over 17)
    {

        if (dealerTotal < 17)
        {
            dealercardNew = rand() % 13 + 1;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "The dealer's new card is: " << dealercardNew << endl;
            if (dealercardNew > 10) // sets jack, queen and king to 10
            {
                dealercardNew = 10;
            }
            dealerTotal = dealerTotal + dealercardNew; // adding new card to total

            cout << "The dealer's new total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;

            if (dealerTotal > 21) // dealer loss
            {
                cout << "The dealer's deck went Bust!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            if (dealerTotal > 17 || dealerTotal == 17)
            {
                cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        else (dealerTotal > 17 || dealerTotal == 17)
            cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
        break; 


    }
}
```

I have Tried removing the last else and turning it into an else if but both do not work.

Removing the else entirely makes it not do anything after the total is read out

Adding else if didnt do anything that i could notice.

The two initial cards are created using this code if helpful:

```
srand(time(NULL));
Pcard1 = rand() % 13 + 1;
Pcard2 = rand() % 13 + 1;
dealercard1 = rand() % 13 + 1;
dealercard2 = rand() % 13 + 1;
```

Comment: What does the code output?

Comment: The dealer's two cards are: 2 & 8
The dealer's total is: 10

The dealer's new card is: 5
The dealer's new total is: 15
You won!

Comment: The final `break;` isn't attached to the `else`. It gets executed unconditionally.

Comment: So it stops at the 15 instead of 17 or higher

Comment: Nathan so what should I add instead because it needs to exit the loop

Comment: Put the statements that are supposed to be executed together between curly braces, like you do for all your `if` statements.

Comment: Sorry im not sure if i understand

Comment: @NathanPierson is right - add curly braces around the else block (the break statement should be inside that block).  Side note on style/readability, try using the >=, and <= operators where appropriate (e.g., replace "if (dealerTotal > 17 || dealerTotal == 17)" with "if (dealerTotal >= 17)".

Comment: [Short example](https://godbolt.org/z/eT3v7dT3b) demonstrating what I mean.

Comment: Ok thank you so much just tried it and it worked!

Comment: Also thank you for the suggestion

Comment: As a side note, this would have been a great time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code and see exactly what lines execute in what manner.

Answer (score 1):

You are not breaking the loop correctly when `17 <= dealerTotal < 21`:

```cpp
else (dealerTotal > 17 || dealerTotal == 17)
    cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
break;
```

First off, the `else` is malformed, it would need to be `else if (...)` instead. But even so, the `break` is simply not attached to the `else` and so it will be executed *unconditionally* at the end of the 1st loop iteration. That is why the dealer takes only 1 card.  It would need to look like this instead:

```cpp
else // dealerTotal >= 17
{ // <-- add this...
    cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
    break; 
} // <-- add this...
```

Try this:

```cpp
if (playerTotal <= 21)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's two cards are: " << dealercard1 << " & " << dealercard2 << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;

    while (loop == 1) // will keep looping until it breaks (over 17)
    {
        if (dealerTotal < 17)
        {
            dealercardNew = rand() % 13 + 1;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "The dealer's new card is: " << dealercardNew << endl;

            if (dealercardNew > 10) // sets jack, queen and king to 10
            {
                dealercardNew = 10;
            }
            dealerTotal += dealercardNew; // adding new card to total
            cout << "The dealer's new total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;

            if (dealerTotal > 21) // dealer loss
            {
                cout << "The dealer's deck went Bust!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            if (dealerTotal >= 17)
            {
                cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be simplified a little bit to remove the redundant check for `dealerTotal >= 17`:

```cpp
if (playerTotal <= 21)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's two cards are: " << dealercard1 << " & " << dealercard2 << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;

    while (loop == 1) // will keep looping until it breaks (over 17)
    {
        if (dealerTotal < 17)
        {
            dealercardNew = rand() % 13 + 1;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "The dealer's new card is: " << dealercardNew << endl;

            if (dealercardNew > 10) // sets jack, queen and king to 10
            {
                dealercardNew = 10;
            }
            dealerTotal += dealercardNew; // adding new card to total
            cout << "The dealer's new total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;

            if (dealerTotal > 21) // dealer loss
            {
                cout << "The dealer's deck went Bust!" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I would suggest simplifying the logic even further by ignoring the `loop` variable, which isn't doing anything useful in this code:

```cpp
if (playerTotal <= 21)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's two cards are: " << dealercard1 << " & " << dealercard2 << endl;
    cout << "The dealer's total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;

    while (dealerTotal < 17)
    {
        dealercardNew = rand() % 13 + 1;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The dealer's new card is: " << dealercardNew << endl;

        if (dealercardNew > 10) // sets jack, queen and king to 10
        {
            dealercardNew = 10;
        }
        dealerTotal += dealercardNew; // adding new card to total
        cout << "The dealer's new total is: " << dealerTotal << endl;
    }

    if (dealerTotal > 21) // dealer loss
    {
        cout << "The dealer's deck went Bust!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The Dealer chose to stand with: " << dealerTotal << endl;
    }
}
```